# x64 Jump instructions

Tags: 64-bit, machine-code

I understand the near jumps that are just offsets with either an immediate value, register, or address.  There should be far (absolute addresses) jumps with immediate value, register, or address too right?  The far instructions list m16:16, m16:32, and m16:64 but what do these mean?  This is on page 853 of the Intel x64 manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the case the "far == absolute"; while all far jumps are absolute, not all absolute jumps are far (see FF /4, call near absolute, optionally indirect).

The far jump is an absolute jump that also writes to `cs`, the m16 part goes into `cs` and the other part is the address jumped to. The precise semantics of the far jump are quite complicated.

So the possible jumps are:

```
          near | far
-----------------------
relative | yes |  no
absolute | yes | yes
indirect | yes | yes
```

Comment: Say I want to jump to 0x1000, what do I put in for m16??

Comment: @RyanBrown nothing, if you just want to jump to 0x1000 then use a near jump. Far jumps are for special occasions.

Comment: Near jumps are offsets of the current instruction though, right?  If I want to jump to 0x1000 then isnt it a far (absolute) jump??

Comment: When would you need a far jump out of curiosity?

Comment: @RyanBrown any time you need to change `cs`, for example if you're in real mode and jumping to some code that is in an other segment, or in longmode when you want to switch between the 32 and 64 bit sub-modes, in some circumstances to leave ring 0 (often that's a far return, but not always)